# how to downcast type in "case of" in haskell

Tags: haskell

I wanted to downcast the type(from C to A), but failed in the sample:

```
data A = One Int
data B = Two Int
fa::A -> Int
fa a = 1

data C = A | B

f::C -> Int
f c = case c of
          A -> fa (c::A)
          _ -> 0
```

the error message is :

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘A’ with actual type ‘C’
In the first argument of ‘fa’, namely ‘(c :: A)’
In the expression: fa (c :: A)
```

How can I do it properly? Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem at hand is not with coercion, but you do mix up the difference between a type - and its instances.

`Type` is the thing on the left hand side of the `=` in a `data`-declaration and all of them live in one name-space. (To indicate the difference I will denote them with bold face).

- **`A`**
- **`B`**
- **`C`**

`Values` or instances of a type are written on the right hand side of the `data`-declaration

- `One Int`
- `Two Int`
- `A` and `B`

Now you try to call a function `fa :: A -> Int` on something of type **`C`** thus resulting in the error.

To fix this there are more solutions

you can write conversion functions that convert `A` to `One 1` and call `fa` on the transformed value - or change the types like [@user2297560](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2297560/user2297560) showed [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505437/630160)

```
data A = One Int
data B = Two Int
data C = A | B

fa :: A -> Int
fa a = 1

convA :: C -> A
convA A = One 1
convA _ = error "not A"

f :: C -> Int
f c = case c of
          A -> fa (convA A)
          _ -> 0
```

or simply by doing it in the definition of `f`

```
f :: C -> Int
f A = fa (One 1)
f _ = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are confusing the data type `A` with the constructor `A` of the data type `C`. The `c` that you pass into function `f` has type `C` which means it is a value constructed with either of the constructors `A` or `B`.  However, values of type `A` and type `B` are constructed with the constructors `One` and `Two` respectively.

Perhaps what you want is something like this instead:

```
data A = One Int
data B = Two Int

fa :: A -> Int
fa a = 1

data C = A A | B B

f :: C -> Int
f c = case c of
          A a -> fa a
          _ -> 0
```

The key difference is that the `C` type now consists of either a value constructed with the `A` constructor that contains a value of type `A` or a value constructed with the `B` constructor that contains a value of type `B`. Of course, you should probably name your constructors something less confusing like `data C = TheA A | TheB B`.  Alternatively, you could use the `Either` type which is isomorphic to your `C`: `type C = Either A B`.

Comment: both of you and Epsilonhalbe have great answers, thanks!